# Display thread id instead thread name in log

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have a Struts application with log4j to display information about application.

The pattern to format log's output is as follows:

```
log4j.appender.RALL.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} [THREAD ID=%t] [CLASS=(%C{1}:%L)] %m%n
```

I need to show the **thread id** instead the **thread name** in log. The conversion character that display the thread name is %t. I don't see in log4j documentation the way to get it.

Can anyone help me??

Comment: Yes, I tried it, but as you say below it only works for IBM Server

Comment: @partlov That don't work for me, `%i` can't be recognized, I am using log4j `1.2.16`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is possible but not so easy as just using some preconfigured patterns.

Log4j 1.X and Log4j 2.x don't have any preconfigured patterns for printing Thread ID but you can always use some "magic trick".

`PatternLayout` is using `PatternParser` class which is mark as `final` class and has static map of "patterns" as keys and `Converters` classes as values. Everytime when Parses finds pattern using for logging pattern format starting with `%` it uses converter matched with this pattern key in map.

You cannot add your own rule to that map, but you can still write your own MyOwnPatternLayout:

```
public class MyOwnPatternLayout extends PatternLayout
```

which will in it's `format` method do such trick:

```
public String format(LoggingEvent event) {
   String log = super.format(event);
   /*
   Now you just have to replace with regex all occurences of %i or 
   any mark you would like to use as mark to represent Thread ID 
   with Thread ID value.
   Only thing you have to be sure to not use any mark as your Thread ID
   that already is defined by PatterParser class
   */
   return log.replaceAll("%i", someThreadID);
}
```

The only problem is that you have to get that thread ID in some way. Sometimes all you have to do is to parse Thread name which can you easily collect:

```
String threadName = event.getThreadName();
```

For example Apache-Tomcat put thread ID at the end of thread name **http-nio-/127.0.0.1-8084"-exec-41**.

To be sure that thread ID is correct you can also make your own subclass of LogginEvent and Logger (MyLoggingEvent and MyLogger) and inside MyLogger create MyLoggingEvent witch will also take as argument Thread ID not only Thread Name. Then you can easly collect it in code above.

Comment: Nop, because when you use `logger.info()` or some other methods from `org.apache.log4j.Logger` then new `LoggingEvent` instance is created and it knows about Thread witch created it but when log is appended to file or console or whatever else by your `MyPatternLayout` it's happen in other Thread and there information about Thread using `logger.info()` only exists inside LoggingEvent instance in other words it's not available with `Thread.currentThread().getId()`. As I wrote you have to subclass a little `Logger` class and `LoggingEvent` class.

Comment: Thanks, The solution I think is to create a LoggingEvent subclass and keep Logger default class because I can't change Logger class in application (more than 500 classes using it). How I can assign MyLoggingEvent class to Logger default class?

Comment: I thinkt you can't and here is a problem if you wont't subclass your own Logger and hide `forcedLog' (ther new `LoggingEvent` is created) method with your own. You can easly ommit using `Logger` in more than 500 classes - just write your own `Logger` nothing differents than standard `Logger` than `fordedLog` method and if you get `Logger` by calling `Logger.getLogger(String/class)` then just change package import in class files from org.apache.log4j.Logger to my.package.name.MyLogger - it's not so much pain and everything will still works.

Comment: Yes, I know it isn't hard to implement but there are enterprise restrictions about commit 500 classes (f..cking burocracy). I will think other solution. A lot of thanks

Comment: Name your commit 'Very Importan Security Update' and bureaucracy will fail! :) Glad I could help even a little.

Comment: Since log4j 2.6 there is a specific [pattern converter for printing thread ID](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1299). In PatternLayout use `pattern="[%tid]"`

Answer (score 9):

One way you can do it is to add it yourself using log4j MDC. We use it for adding the username for web requests. We do this in a filter at the start of each request. Eg.

```
import org.apache.log4j.MDC;

...

  // Add username to MDC
  String username = ...;
  MDC.put("user", username);
```

Then add `[%X{user}]` to your conversion pattern.

Answer (score 7):

I implemented thread ID and thread priority for the upcoming 2.6. Tracking here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1299

You can pick up a 2.6-SNAPSHOT build from the Apache snapshots repository: https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/

Answer (score 5):

You can use the ThreadContext Map to supply meta-data to log4j2.  This is a String Map of values that you **CAN** add through normal formatting.

```
String threadId = String.valueOf(Thread.currentThread().getId());
ThreadContext.put("TId", threadId);
```

And a much more reasonable Pattern:

```
    <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyyMMdd}T%d{HHmmss.SSS} %-5level [%t] [%5X{TId}] %15c{1} - %msg%n"/>
```

[Full Log4j2 documentation on "Fish Tagging"](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/thread-context.html)

Answer (score 5):

I don't know when it is introduced but in log4j2 we have **%tid** for

> Outputs the ID of the thread that generated the logging event.

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html

Answer (score 2):

I think it is not possible to show thread id with standard log4j formatting. I also investigated through code of `PatterParser` class an found nothing which can be useful. I found some custom solutions, but only for IBM server which has `%i` option:

> %i: Inserts the thread ID. Unlike the thread name (indicated by %t), this is thread's numeric ID.
>   Note that this parameter is particular to Initiate, while the other parameters listed here are standard with log4j.

See [this link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/initiate/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.einstall.doc%2Ftopics%2Fc_einstall_understand_conversionpattern_format.html)

Comment: Does it strike (painfully) anybody else but me that despite numerous revisions and a version 2 of log4j that so handily/uselessly changed the config file format from properties to xml, that there is no simple way to add thread id, something that would actually be useful to the USE of the product? Is it possible that we're ALL missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Extend `PatternLayout` as below, and then specify `MyPatternLayout` with `$X{threadId}` in the format string.

This implementation uses `ThreadLocal` to minimize the performance impact of calculating the Thread ID:

```
    MyPatternLayout extends PatternLayout {

        private final ThreadLocal<String> threadId = new ThreadLocal<String>() {

            @Override
            protected String initialValue() {
                String t = Long.toString(Thread.currentThread().getId());
                MDC.put("threadId", t);
                return t;
            }
        };

        @Override
        public String format(LoggingEvent event) {

            this.threadId.get();
            return super.format(event);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to create your own class which sits between your code and Log4J and appends the thread ID to every log message:

```java
public class ThreadLogger
{
    // Constructor declared private to prevent instantiation.  Use static methods instead.
    private ThreadLogger() {}

    private static enum LogLevel
    {
        TRACE,
        DEBUG,
        INFO,
        WARN,
        ERROR
    }

    public static void trace(String message)
    {
        logMessage(message, LogLevel.ERROR);
    }

    public static void debug(String message)
    {
        logMessage(message, LogLevel.ERROR);
    }

    public static void info(String message)
    {
        logMessage(message, LogLevel.ERROR);
    }

    public static void warn(String message)
    {
        logMessage(message, LogLevel.WARN);
    }

    public static void error(String message)
    {
        logMessage(message, LogLevel.ERROR);
    }

    private static void logMessage(String message, LogLevel logLevel)
    {
        // Get the Log4J logger for the class that originally wanted to log the message
        String callingClassName = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[3].getClassName();
        Class callingClass;
        try
        {
            callingClass = Class.forName(callingClassName);
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            String errorMessage = String.format("Could not reference class [%s].  Unable to log call!", callingClassName);
            throw new RuntimeException(errorMessage);
        }
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(callingClass);

        // Get the thread ID and place it in front of the logged message
        long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
        String formattedMessage = String.format("[%s] %s", threadId, message);

        // Log the message
        switch(logLevel)
        {
            case TRACE:
                logger.trace(formattedMessage);
                break;
            case DEBUG:
                logger.debug(formattedMessage);
                break;
            case INFO:
                logger.info(formattedMessage);
                break;
            case WARN:
                logger.warn(formattedMessage);
                break;
            case ERROR:
                logger.error(formattedMessage);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Downsides:

- Performance?  This adds a few extra steps to every log statement.
- Stability?  This adds a potential point of failure (the Class.forName call).
- You have to replace all of your existing log statements with calls to the new class.
- The thread ID won't appear until after the regular Log4J formatting.  IE:

```html
1234 [main] INFO com.foo.bar.Baz - [1] Hello world on thread #1!
1234 [main] INFO com.foo.bar.Baz - [2] Hello world on thread #2!
```

Answer (score 0):

I create my own appender and set Thread.currentThread().getId() to the MDC property. %X{threadId} should give me the thread id. This solution is working since 1.2.15. You can then attach AsyncAppender to this.

```
public class CurrentThreadIdAppender extends AppenderSkeleton implements AppenderAttachable {

    private final AppenderAttachableImpl appenders = new AppenderAttachableImpl();

...

    @Override
    protected void append(LoggingEvent event) {   
        synchronized (appenders) {
            event.setProperty("threadId", String.valueOf(Thread.currentThread().getId()));
            appenders.appendLoopOnAppenders(event);
        }
    }

...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another elegant solution with log4j2 is to use `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.LogEventPatternConverter`.

You can write a class like this

```
@Plugin(name = "ThreadIdConverter", category = "Converter")
@ConverterKeys({ "tid" })
public class ThreadIdConverter extends LogEventPatternConverter {

    protected ThreadIdConverter(String name, String style) {
        super(name, style);
    }

    @Override
    public void format(LogEvent event, StringBuilder toAppendTo) {
        toAppendTo.append(getThreadId());
    }

    protected String getThreadId() {
        long id = Thread.currentThread().getId();
        return Long.toHexString(id);
    }

    public static ThreadIdConverter newInstance(String[] options) {
        return new ThreadIdConverter("tid", "tid");
    }
}
```

In this way you are creating a new pattern `tid` and you can use it when you define your appender's layout

```
<Appenders>
    <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%d{dd-MMM HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-7level [%5tid] %logger - %message%n</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
    </Console>
</Appenders>
```

The last important thing to remember is how to activate your log4j2 plugin. To do it you have to add the package that contains your plugins in the log4j2 configuration file using the `package` attribute on `Configuration` node

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE Configuration>
<Configuration status="warn"
    packages="my.package.logging.plugins">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d{dd-MMM HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-7level [%5tid] %logger - %message%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="warn">
            <AppenderRef ref="console" />
        </Root>
        <Logger name="my.package" level="trace" />
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: This will only work, if you do not log asynchronously (e.g. with AsyncLogger)!