# generate every request log4j in a group in java

Tags: java, logging

We are facing issue with log4j because logs are jumbled. in multiple requests logs are not printed request wise they get mesh up and information which we want to analysis is not an easy job.

Please suggest what can be do with this scenario.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “jumbled“? Do you see time stamps out of sequence?

Answer (score 0):

Log4J is going to write output in arrival sequence.  It is curious that the Thread ID is not part of the standard output.  In Log4J V1.x -- LONG since deprecated and you shouldn't be using, it is fairly simple to add the Thread ID to the format.

In Log4J2 it is actually amazingly difficult, or at least not remotely obvious, how to get this VITAL piece of information.  [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359044/display-thread-id-instead-thread-name-in-log/25368662#25368662) should tell you everything you need to know about it.

Bottom line you should be using the log4j declarative formatting in your log4j.xml file to get consistent logging.  Seldom do you get anything maintainable, or even readable, if you leave programmers to figure out their own log formatting.

Comment: I don’t understand what you are talking about. Using Log4j2’s pattern format (https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout), both thread name (`%t`) and thread id (`%T` or `%tid`) are standard and easy to configure.

Comment: HA!  I didn't know they finally added that.  It was a GROSS oversight.  The only thing more important than the thread Id is the message payload itself.  TID is WAY more important than timestamp.  Like OP complained, without that you have less than nothing.  Glad to see they finally got their heads out of their collective asses.

Comment: Are we talking about the same thing? Thread name has been there from the beginning (and is generally far more useful than the thread ID which is just a number). Thread ID was added years ago.

Comment: In a tomcat environment Thread name is essentially worthless.  Thread ID is infinitely useful and is the only way to tie one log statement to another.  I came up with a solution using their “fish tagging” approach back when thread ID wasn’t available.  I actually got a lot of abuse for not just using log4j V1 since it had “THE single most important feature”.  I (obviously) haven’t revisited the log4j doc in years.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Sorry to hear you got abuse for recommending people to upgrade.